# How does the signature in a digital certificate come from?

Tags: encryption, certificate, public-key-encryption, digital-certificate, pki

According to [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate#Contents_of_a_typical_digital_certificate):

A digital certificate contains:

- Serial Number: Used to uniquely identify the certificate.
- Subject: The person, or entity identified.
- Signature Algorithm: The algorithm used to create the signature.
- **Signature**: The actual signature to verify that it came from the
  issuer.
- Issuer: The entity that verified the information and issued the
  certificate.
- Valid-From: The date the certificate is first valid from.
- Valid-To: The expiration date.
- Key-Usage: Purpose of the public key (e.g. encipherment, signature,
  certificate signing...).
- Public Key: The public key.
- Thumbprint Algorithm: The algorithm used to hash the public key
  certificate.
- Thumbprint (also known as fingerprint): The hash itself, used as an
  abbreviated form of the public key certificate.

My question is, how does the **signature** come from? I think it is used to ensure the digital certificate is issued by a trusted issuer. So the issuer use its private key to sign on **something** to produce the signature, then the verifier of the certificate must have the corresponding public key of the issuer to decipher the signature and verify that this **something** is genuine.

If I am correct, this **something** must be stored in the certificate as well for the verifier to compare the deciphered signature to. So what's this **something**? Could it be the thumbprint (hash) of the public key?

Answer (score 5):

This something is most of the certificate itself. The receiver can calculate the hash over the TBSCertificate (the part of the certificate To Be Signed) itself using the algorithm in the certificate. The receiver can then verify that it is the same as the hash calculated by the signer (the issuer of the certificate). If the signature is verified and the signer is trusted, then the certificate is *verified*.

There are more tests to be performed such as validating that the certificate has not been revoked or over it's date of expiry before it can be fully trusted.

A digital certificate consists of:

1. certificate information
2. signature algorithm
3. signature value

See the [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1) for more info on the exact structure of the certificate.

Comment: I've made the answer a bit more precise, please let me know if the changes are easy to understand. You can roll them back if you don't agree. Note that the hashing is officially *part of the signature algorithm*, it's not a separate step.

Comment: @owlstead *This hash can be retrieved from the signature* - strictly speaking a candidate hash can only be tested against the signature. Extraction is possible only for some algorithms.

Comment: My answer was trying more to convey the principles of what happens than to be technically accurate. I linked to the RFC for the technical details.

Comment: @user18044 Your original answer did not imply that the originally signed hash could be *retrieved*, merely that a document hash could be *verified*. Even though owlstead's edit did improve you answer in other aspects, it in this respect introduced inaccuracy.

Comment: @mkl It was late last night when I replied, so maybe I did not grasp what you were saying. But to verify the signature, the public key of the signer is used to decrypt the value and get back the hash, not? Not sure how owlstead's comment is inaccurate.

Comment: *to verify the signature, the public key of the signer is used to decrypt the value and get back the hash, not?* - that essentially is how it is done for RSA signatures. DSA and ECDSA are different.